# Dialog Window closed before reaching to done(Accepted);

Tags: c++, qt

I have something that is strange , I have Dialog window that I trigger from MainWIndow like this:

```
//this is from main window 
DialogUpdateContainer dialogUpdateContainer(this);
  dialogUpdateContainer.getFileName(m_new_version_name);
  if(dialogUpdateContainer.exec(&#41; == QDialog::Accepted ) 
  {
      return true;
  }
```

And in the `DialogUpdateContainer`
I have this simple code :

```
DialogUpdateContainer::DialogUpdateContainer( QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent),   
                                                                 ui(new Ui::DialogUpdate)
{
    ui->setupUi( this );
    pHttpDownloadManager = new HttpDownloadManager();

    connect(ui->buttonBox,
    SIGNAL(accepted()),
    this, 
    SLOT(OkSettingsHandler())); 

   connect(ui->buttonBox,
           SIGNAL(rejected()),
           this,
         SLOT(CancelSettingsHandler()));
}

void DialogUpdateContainer::getFileName(QString& fileNameToDownload)
{
    fileToDownload = fileNameToDownload;
}

void DialogUpdateContainer::OkSettingsHandler()
{
    if(pHttpDownloadManager->downloadFile(fileToDownload&#41;)
{
    done(Accepted);
}

}
void DialogUpdateContainer::CancelSettingsHandler()
{
    done(Rejected);
}
```

Now the problem is when I click the ok in the dialog windows its closing immediately without waiting for `pHttpDownloadManager->downloadFile(fileToDownload&);` to finish 
its even never gets to the done(Accepted);
Why ?
I want it to wait to until it done the function and only then to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very odd:

```
 if(dialogUpdateContainer.exec(&#41; == QDialog::Accepted ) {

     return true;
  }
```

Normal:

```
 if(dialogUpdateContainer.exec()==QDialog::Accepted ) {

     return true;
  }
```